# Why Regex not working?

Tags: php, regex

I have simple PHP regex to extract all content within `<body></body>`

Regex is

```
<body>(.*?)<\/body>
```

This is the text

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="http://localhost//themes/default/../dashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost//assets/cache/default_product_groups_product_groups_mod.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost//favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <p dir='rtl'>
     <a target='_blank' href='https://zuz.mx/2e5y'>לרכישה מכאן במחיר 37.01$</a>
    </p>

    <input id="base_url_special" type="hidden" name="base_url_special" value="http://localhost//"/>

</body>
<script src="http://localhost//themes/default/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://localhost//assets/cache/default_fetchPG_product_groups_mod.js?_dt=1492617362" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost//themes/default/../dashboard/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the live example https://regex101.com/r/joLaTm/1

Comment: Not with `/gmi` just with `/s`.

Comment: You are already using a tool that explains exactly what the expression does, so make use of that information. It says: *"`.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the explanation section of your live example.

> `.*` matches any character (**except for line terminators**)

Add the `s` flag to your regex. https://regex101.com/r/joLaTm/3

Comment: Also how to exclude BODY tags from results? I tried this but it only excludes the ending body tag `/(=?<body>)(.*?)(?=<\/body>)/ism`

Comment: @Umair No need, that's already how it works. Don't use the "full match", use the "group 1" result, which is just the `(.*?)` portion of it. It'll probably be in `$matches[1]` assuming you're using `preg_match` in the way the docs advise.

Comment: @ceejayoz there is a typo in the lookbehind op uses

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the single line option to make `.` match new lines (see [fork](https://regex101.com/r/DTr366/1) of your test). Or use `[\S\s]*`

Comment: Also how to exclude BODY tags from results? I tried this but it only excludes the ending body tag `/(=?<body>)(.*?)(?=<\/body>)/ism`

Comment: @Umair Your first result set should exclude the body tags already.

Comment: @Umair try with `(?<=<body>)(.*?)(?=<\/body>)`